# Failed to execute 'getTotalLength'

Tags: javascript, svg

i am using JS to generate an inline SVG. I use `getTotalLength()` to calculate some `stroke-dasharray` values to animate polylines.

This all works fine, whenever i execute my `draw()` function the very first time. However, when i execute the same function a second time to add some additional polylines, it does not work. Instead it throws:

```
Error: Failed to execute 'getTotalLength' on 'SVGGeometryElement': This element is non-rendered element.
```

Existing stackoverflow posts do not match this question.

Thank you for your help.

Using: Up to date Chrome version and simple JS.

Comment: _ This element is non-rendered element_  on what element are you trying to execute the getTotalLength? It would be nice to see an example.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using UIkit? Take a look at [this Github issue](https://github.com/uikit/uikit/issues/4132).

**EDIT**

Seems it's not UIkit-specific as I originally thought (the grammar of the error message didn't look like it came from a JS engine).

But checking out the pull request that fixes the linked issue, it does seem that this error occurs when an element isn't visible, since length is only computable when there are drawn artifacts associated with the element.

Visibility is testable by checking if any of the element's nodes have an `offsetWidth`, `offsetHeight`, or bounding boxes (`getClientRects()`).

Comment: No, using SVG.js to instantiate the SVG objects. However, i am calling getTotalLength() on the actual DOM objects... Which works in the first draw() call and fails in every consecutive call.

Comment: @BoA456 you *need* to add code. Otherwise we will not be able to help you!

Comment: I had an awful time trying to understand this error, and some of this info helped, so I need to add a comment. I've experienced this getTotalLength error while using animejs and Ionic. I was animating SVG elements. Ionic cached the page somewhere, and when I entered the page again, the animation would try to start on the previous page reference instead of on the new one. The former page reference had no visible elements, so I guess that's how the error appeared. I had to overpass the Ionic cache to make it work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little surprised that this issue doesn't have more views.
I ran into the exact same problem, unknown to me since my webpage only threw the error for a specific view-size (essentially where I was hiding the element).
My CSS was using opacity set to zero for an @media rule with Samsung Ultra series:

@media only screen and (max-width: 415px)

This is a snippet of my HTML:

```
    <div class="counter-container">
        <span class="time">0:00</span>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 110 110">
            <circle class="background" cx="55" cy="55" r="50"></circle>
            <circle class="main" cx="55" cy="55" r="50"></circle>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

I was using MS Edge with plain JavaScript:

```
    const container = document.querySelector('.counter-container');
    const circle    = document.querySelector('.counter-container > svg > circle.main');

    let length = circle.getTotalLength().round(2);
```

Not sure if this will help others, but my solution consisted of detecting whether the parent DIV had full opacity with an "IF" statement and wrapping the  code within the conditional.

My error was very similar ...

```
    Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getTotalLength' on 'SVGGeometryElement': This element is non-rendered element.
```

Note: Waiting for the document to be loaded and the triggering the code did not resolve my issue.  I also tried putting my JavaScript code at the end of the html, but to no avail.

This is a snippet of my solution ...

```
    let length = 0;
    
    if (container.style.opacity == 1) { // alternate: if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 415) {
      length = circle.getTotalLength().round(2);
    }
    circle.style.strokeDasharray = length;
    circle.style.strokeDashoffset = 0;
```